# SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges fails after migrating app to Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms application that has some code that gets values from a SharePoint site. It was working fine until we migrated the app to use Azure AD authentication.

I'm guessing it's due to the fact that the identity from Azure AD is different from what SharePoint expects? The error is:

> Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Parameter
>   name: encodedValue

... it's being thrown by this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    ...
});
```

Users in the SharePoint site are identified as `<domain>\username`, while the identity provided by AAD is the user's e-mail address. Is there a way I can configure AAD to return `<domain>\username` instead?

Comment: Is this `<domain>\username` in your Local AD ? AAD doesn't support down-level name for login. If you really want to use this instead the UPN to login, I'm afraid of you need to setup AD FS and integrate your on-premise with AAD.

Comment: Yes it is, but we’re required to authenticate via AAD.

Comment: Sorry for this situation, AAD doesn't support this kind sign in name becuase AAD authentication is based on Oauth/OIDC.

Comment: So there's no way for me to use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`??

Comment: For now, I think there is no way to use this directly.